# How can I securely store a ruby hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I need to map to different logic based on a unique id parameter.  I essentially want to do the following:

```
{
  'id123' => send(:foo),
  'id789' => send(:bar)
}
```

I wouldn't want to hardcode the variables, and storing each ID in a separate environment variable is tedious and difficult to keep track of. The best solution I can think of is converting the hash to a string to store as an env var, then converting back to a hash when I initialize the app but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I would hard code it but let it get overridden by env vars, if they are set. You can use `ENV.fetch("some_key", "default_value")`

Comment: Sounds like you need to break this out into separate routes & controllers responsible for hanging each unique action. i.e. `/bar/:id` would execute `send(:bar)` and `/foo/:id` would execute `send(:foo)`

Comment: Are you looking to do something like secrets storage? https://medium.com/@kirill_shevch/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rails custom configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) with `Rails::Application.config_for`:

```yaml
# config/id_to_method_mapping.yml:
id123: "foo"
id789: "bar"
```

```rb
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.id_to_method_mapping = config_for(:id_to_method_mapping)
  end
end
```

```rb
# your controller
method_name = Rails.configuration.id_to_method_mapping[params[:id]]
send(method_name)
```

You can .gitignore the config file if you don't want it to be in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood your question correctly but for your own solution of converting the hash, you can use `Object Marshaling` in Ruby to serialize any object (e.g. Hash). That's what some libraries like `Sidekiq` do and store the serialized object, for example in `Redis`.

```
class Demo
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def to_s
    p "Serializing #{@name}"
  end
end

obj = Demo.new("something...")
obj_d = Marshal.dump(o)
obj2 = Marshal.load(obj_d)
obj2.to_s
```

And you can always use `eval` to dynamically evaluate an expression: `eval("obj2.to_s")`.